# Having issues with SUMIFS formula in excel for two criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that contains MIC values for a drug. I have another column that contains a binary response if a particular gene is present...its either "YES" or "NO".

Column A contains the name of each sample. Column B contains MICs ranging from 0.03 to 16. Column C contains "YES" or "NO". I'd like a formula that counts the number of "YES" with respect to MICs of 16 only.

Can someone help me? My formula keeps returning 0.

The formula I'm using is:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C349,A2:A349,"YES",B2:B349,"16")
```

Comment: You want to count or sum they are two different things with different formula.

Comment: I need to sum the counts of each "YES" for each MIC. For example I need to know how many YES values I get for the MIC of 16. By filtering I know the answer is 16 in my worksheet. However I'd prefer a formula.

Comment: So you want to COUNT the YESes for each MIC.  SUMIFS() sums a numeric value not count a text string, which is why you are getting `0`.  Use COUNTIFS() not SUMIFS()

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C349,"YES",B2:B349,"16")
```

Comment: I feel like a dummy but this was the correct formula. Thank you Scott!

Comment: @user3105519 don't feel that way, we all do this.  We all get anchored on one thought stream and need a third party at times to remove that anchor.